# Hanging Drywall Against Finished Ceiling

Tags: drywall

I removed the drywall on my walls as part of a bathroom renovation project and now I am at the stage where I put up new drywall on the walls. I did not remove the ceiling drywall so I am going to butt the new drywall on the walls up to the finished ceiling from before. Can I simply tape these joints against the ceiling without removing the previous tape and finish or should I scrape the portion of the ceiling that the new tape will be applied before I put on the new tape?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to completely scrape down but you will need to at least rough up the existing ceiling out to the distance of your final mud coat, to facilitate good adhesion of the new joint compound (assuming existing is painted plaster/drywall, if other then please state so).

Comment: By roughing up do you mean strip it down or do you mean just rough it up with some coarse sand paper or something similar?

Comment: Sandpaper or similar